# Do I have to explicity close all streams, if they're wrapped in a buffer via java?

Tags: java, networking

```
private InputStream input;
private InputStreamReader inputReader;
private BufferedReader reader;

try {
    input = new InputStream();
    inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    // do I/O operations
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("IOException", "The Data Could Not Be Read =/");
} finally {
    try {
        reader.close(); // now will this, by default, close all other streams? OR
      /*
       * input.close(); inputStream.close(); //is this necessary, along with
       * reader.close();
       */
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I came across this question today, and am not sure whether they'll be closed, since it's wrapped, or if it is still necessary to close all streams
independently.

Comment: It does close all related streams... but it wouldn't hurt putting the other ones

Comment: @3kings - Well, I would argue that redundant code does hurt. Better to rely on the contract of `close()` than add extra calls on each reader/stream just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If any reader or stream decorates another reader/stream, then closing the outer one also closes the inner. This can be implied from the Javadoc of [`Closeable#close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html#close--):

> Closes this stream and releases **any** system resources associated with it.

That applies to the underlying resources, too.

If you're very curious you can dig into the sources of those classes, eg. in `BufferedReader`:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (in == null)
            return;
        try {
            in.close();
        } finally {
            in = null;
            cb = null;
        }
    }
}
```

where `in` is the underlying `Reader`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, decorated streams are closed too.

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("c:\\myfile.txt");
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

bufferedReader.close();

in.read(); // throws an IOException (no such file or directory)
reader.read(); // throws an IOException (Stream closed)
```

Answer (score 4):

From Java 7 you can use the try-with-resource block (and the fact that closing `reader` closes the others)

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                              new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"))) {

    // do I/O operations
} catch(IOException e) {
    Log.d("IOException", "The Data Could Not Be Read =/", e);
}
```